# URL Structure - http://www.mysite.com/Category/Product

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET - MVC

I want the URL to show the Category & Product.

Example:

http://www.mytestweb.com/%%category%%/%%product%%

```
    routes.MapLocalizedRoute("CategoryProduct",
                   "{CategoryName/{ProductName}",
                   new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Product" },
                   new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });



   public ActionResult Product(int productId)
    {
        var category = getcategoryfromProductId(productID);
        //show category in URL
         .............. ??
    }
```

I can retrieve the category name from the DB but I have no idea how to actually show the category in the URL.  The above only returns the Product Name in the URL which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route is correct (except for the typo -- should be `"{CategoryName/{ProductName}"`).  The catch is that, for this route to be recognized, its action needs to accept all non-optional parameters from the route definition:

```
public ActionResult Product(string CategoryName, string ProductName)
{
    // lookup ProductID
}
```

Assuming the product ID is needed, you'll have to look that up somehow given category + product name.